# check for a value in all the child divs of a particular parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project. I am trying to check whether a certain number already present in any other adjacent `div`'s which are present in a parent div.

```
  //generated dynamically using jQuery
  <div> //parent div
      //many div's
      //one of the child div is selected by the user.
  </div>
  <div> //another parent div
     //my function is checking one of these div's instead of the above, rarely
  </div>
```

---

I used the following below code. but it sometimes(rarely) selecting the another parent `div`'s child elements which I dont want to check for (I checked with debugger in chrome). and if sometimes even if the function selects the correct parent div it is always selecting the same child div element which is selected by the user.

**jQuery**

```
function checkInGroup(){
    var selectedDiv = $('#' + _selectedDivId); //updated after engineer's comment
    selectedDiv.parent("div").children().each(function(){
        debugger;
        if(this !== selectedDiv[0]){ //selecting the same div
            var self = $(this);
            if(self.text() == _randomNumber){
                debugger; //never executing
                //do some function here
            }
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT:  I am not sure why my code is not working when it is working fine in **[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iviwej/1/edit)**. I need to check why so.. It is always checking with the same user selected div?? Hence the function is not entering into the if statement..

The `debugger` which is present inside the if statement is never executing. and also the each function loop is happening only once with the same selected div (hence the function is not entering in to the if statement)

Here is the **[jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/iviwej/17/edit)**

Comment: Change `if($(this) !== selectedDiv){ ` to `if(this !== selectedDiv[0]){ ` as you need to compare DOM elements themselves, not jQuery wrappers on those elements. Even `$(this) !== $(this)` expression is *always* `true`, as there are 2 different wrappers(objects).

Comment: @Engineer Thanks for the suggestion. I will keep this in mind. Please check my updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) .

```
$('#' + _selectedDivId).siblings().each(function(){

});
```

Updated:

selectedDiv id is not actually div it is button id. that's the problem. please
change your code like below.

```
   selectedDiv.parent("div").parent("div").find("button").each(function(){
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/iviwej/18/edit)

Comment: @Mr_Green: if(`self.text()` == _randomNumber){ what is `self` here?

Comment: did you check `if(self.text() == _randomNumber){` this condition with debugging? you code is perfect no issue in your code.

Comment: Thats what I am confused about.. the loop of `each` is happening only once and that time `if(this !== selectedDiv[0]){` is true. so, no way that the inside code is being executed.. My created samples with same code works fine.. I am doing something wrong which I cant figure it out..

Comment: http://jsbin.com/iviwej/17/edit  Its a sample of my big code.. Here I am trying to show background red . I hope you can understand the code. (here numbers 11,13,14 should be with background red)

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
 selectedDiv.parent("div").children().not(selectedDiv).each(function(){
   //your code 
 });
```

Comment: you are selecting the next parent div here instead of doing the function in the same parent div. I want to check each child element for a value in that parent div only.

Comment: So I puzzled, what's wrong with the answer I posted before updating?

Comment: the `next` is selecting the other child div, which is exactly what I want but it is always checking the same selected next div...

Comment: In my now post, I use `siblings()`

Comment: why there is a need of `sibling()` here I cant understand.. I just need to check all the child div values only in the parent div in which the selected child div is present..

Comment: So I first not use `siblings()`, does it not work? maybe you can show a jsfiddle

Comment: I am not sure why my code is not working when it is working fine in [`jsbin`](http://jsbin.com/iviwej/1/edit). I need to check why so.. It is always checking with the same user selected div?? Hence the function is not entering into the if statement..

Comment: The `debugger` which is inside is never executing and the each function looping only once(checking with the same selected div)

Answer (score 2):

The $.each() function has an actual signature of $.each([Array], index, element). In your case:

```
function checkInGroup(){
    var selectedDiv = $('#' + _selectedDivId);
    $.each(selectedDiv.parent("div").children(), function(index, element){
        debugger;
        if($(element) !== selectedDiv){ //selecting the same div
            if($(element).text() == _randomNumber){
                //do some function here
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `$.each()` and `.each()` are two different methods.

Answer (score 0):

`selectedDiv` may be an array in your example.

I don't think you can compare two jQuery objects like this.

You could consider using data attributes?

e.g.

```
var selectedDiv = $('#' + _selectedDivId);
selectedDiv.data('selected', true);
```

then

```
selectedDiv.parent("div").children().each(function(){
    debugger;
    if($(this).data('selected') !== true){ //selecting the same div
        if($(this).text() == _randomNumber){
            //do some function here
        }
    }
});
```

Just remember to set `selected` to false on the div when it's deselected.

There's probably a more efficient way to do this but this should work.